# Convergence of $n^2/n!$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

im trying to solve a simple excercise but i can't solve it, it says:

> Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$$ converges to 0.

I can't see how i can make 
$$|\frac{n^2}{n!}-0|<\epsilon$$
i was doing a similar probem for $\frac{2^n}{n!}$, where you can control $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2}$, but i can't find a way to control the inequality in this exercise, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work?: n^2/n! = n/(n-1)! Lim(n/n-1)=1 and Lim(1/(n-2)!) = 0 therefore lim(n^2/n!) =0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n(n-1)}\frac1{(n-2)!}\\
&=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n(n-1)}}_1\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{(n-2)!}}_0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{nn}{(n-1)!n}$,so it's enough to prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=0$ and that is true simply because $n<(n-1)!$ for all $n>3$

Edit: As pointed out by robjohn, the fact that $n<(n-1)!$ is not enough. It could be the case that $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=c<1$ for some constant $c$ but this is not the case because the distance between the numerator and the denominator goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity. To see that observe that: $$(n-1)!-n=(n-1)!-(n-1)-1=(n-1)((n-2)!-1)-1$$ and $(n-2)!$ goes to infinity, so does $(n-2)!-1$, and also $n-1$ goes to infinity, so $(n-1)((n-2)!-1)-1$ goes to infinity

Comment: Just because $n\lt(n-1)!$, does not mean the ratio tends to 0.

Comment: @robjohn yes, you're right! I'll see if I can fix it or I'll delete it